# How to select a text in Word and convert it to stacked fraction with vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I try to select the text in Word, for example:

```
10/8
18/6
12/4
```

And with macros convert it to this type of fractions with the horizontal line:

```
Sub EscribeFraccion()

    Dim objRango As Range
    Dim objEq As OMath
     
    Set objRango = Selection.Range
    objRango.Text = "9/36"
    Set objRango = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRango)
    Set objEq = objRango.OMaths(1)
    objEq.BuildUp
    
End Sub
```

I would like all that text to be selected and each item to be converted like this.

I have this code that what it does is ask you through a text box, the fraction:

```
Sub MakeFraction ()
Dim Fraction As String, Numerator As String, Denominator As String
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
With Selection
  'For user input, you could use the following 2 lines to create a fraction
   Fraction = InputBox ("Please input the Fraction (ex: 1/2, 5/32)")
   .Collapse (wdCollapseStart)
  'Alternatively, to convert a selection, use the following line
  'Fraction = Trim (.Text)
  Numerator = Split (Fraction, "/") (0)
  Denominator = Split (Fraction, "/") (1)
  .Font.Size = Round (.Font.Size) / 2
  .Fields.Add Range: = Selection.Range, Type: = wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting: = False, Text: = "EQ \ f (" & Numerator & "," & Denominator & ")"
  .MoveLeft wdCharacter, 2
  .Delete
  .Fields.Update
End With
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End Sub
```

But instead of the `imput`, I would like to implement this:`StrFrac = Split (Selection.Text, "/")`
How could I do it? I thank you very much in advance for your support. Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```vb
Sub EscribeFraccion()
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find  'or Selection.Range.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]@/[0-9]@"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            .Parent.OMaths.Add(.Parent).OMaths(1).BuildUp
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

### Edit2

```vb
Sub EscribeFraccionSel()
    With Selection.Range.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]@/[0-9]@"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            .Parent.Text = InputBox("Please input the Fraction (ex: 1/2, 5/32)", "Input the Fraction", .Parent.Text)
            .Parent.OMaths.Add(.Parent).OMaths(1).BuildUp
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

### Edit3

```vb
Sub EscribeFraccionSel()
    Dim inp
    With Selection.Range.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]@/[0-9]@"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            inp = Trim(InputBox("Please input the Fraction (ex: 1/2, 5/32)", "Input the Fraction", .Parent.Text))
            inp = Split(inp, "/")
            If UBound(inp) = 1 Then
                If IsNumeric(inp(0)) And IsNumeric(inp(1)) Then
                    .Parent.Text = inp(0) & "/" & inp(1)
                    .Parent.OMaths.Add(.Parent).OMaths(1).BuildUp
                Else
                    MsgBox "Error in the entered fraction"
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Error in the entered fraction"
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Nop, no work. Nothing happens when I run it, why?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Maybe the active document has not text like "1/2"? 1) make shure that the active document is right, 2) try to debug the code step-by-step

Comment: Works, but no in textbox, but works :). How do I make the fractions be done inside a textbox and do the same with each and every element inside that textbox?

Comment: @Spvda see Edit2 and Edit3 samples

Comment: Wow, excelent. One more thing, to avoid asking me if I want to choose "x" fraction and directly convert it without asking me anything, how do I do it? Sorry for not knowing anything about vba, I'm just getting started. Greetings!